# Angular App in Internet Explorer can´t handle XHR with id

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I finished my Angular-CLI App and want to run it on a Surface RT.
The Surface RT is using internet explorer and after adding all imports in polyfills.ts it shows correctly.

MY Problem is, that all my XHR with id aren´t working.
Simple methods where i call on my .php api files are handled correctly, but if there is a need for specific id it isn´t working.

this works fine:

```
getAll(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/userList.php`).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        this.users = res['data'];
        this.getUserItems();
        return this.users;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

but if i give an id like this it doesn´t work in IE:

```
delete(id: number): Observable<User[]> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('id', id.toString());

    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/deleteUser.php`, {params: params})
      .pipe(map(res => {
          const filteredUsers = this.users.filter((user) => {
            return +user['id'] !== +id;
          });
          return this.users = filteredUsers;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Firefox and Chrome are working correctly, only IE is messing around. Is there a way to fix this or a way to setup the Surface RT in any other way like installing android or something?

Comment: what does 'messing around' means? As in, what error do you see?

Comment: there is no error. It just can´t send something like deleteUser.php?id=2.